# How to load additional parameter in CMAKE using ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}?

Tags: cmake

I want to pass an additional parameter to cmake relative to where it is.

My libraries are in:

```
C:/bla/imgui
C:/bla/imgui-integration
```

From 
C:/bla/imgui-integration/build folder I want to refer to C:/bla/imgui in a parameter named IMGUI_DIR :

```
cmake .. -DIMGUI_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../imgui"
```

The problem is that I tried every combination of :

```
-DIMGUI_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../imgui"
-DIMGUI_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/imgui"
```

And none of them works.

Only works if I directly use:

```
-DIMGUI_DIR="C:/bla/imgui"
```

What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: Are you on linux?

Comment: no, I am on windows.

Comment: `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is a **CMake variable**, which is set by CMake when it interprets your project. But when running `cmake <..>` you use **shell scripting**. You need to use abilities of the shell for prepare needed parameters.

Comment: Ok now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Tsyvarev said in a comment:

> CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR is a CMake variable, which is set by CMake
>   when it interprets your project. But when running cmake <..> you use
>   shell scripting. You need to use abilities of the shell for prepare
>   needed parameters

I can't use cmake variables in the shell that will be interpreted inside cmake.